# Text Mining R Package & Regex to handle Replace Smart Curly Quotes

Tags: r, regex, text-mining

I've got a bunch of texts like this below with different smart quotes - for single and double quotes. All I could end up with the packages I'm aware of is to remove those characters but I want them to replaced with the normal quotes.

```
textclean::replace_non_ascii("You don‘t get “your” money’s worth")
```

Received Output: `"You dont get your moneys worth"`

Expected Output: `"You don't get "your" money's worth"`

Also would appreciate if someone's got the regex to replace every such quotes in one shot.

Thanks!

Comment: You do not need to use capturing group/backreference if you just want to normalize quotes as `"`. Use `gsub("[“”]", "\"", text)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But that would assume that the OP wants to replace _all_ curly quotes, even when not surrounding words.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That is exactly what OP is doing when cleaning up texts. Normalizing all quotes.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear earlier. @WiktorStribiżew is right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use two `gsub` operations: 1) to replace double curly quotes, 2) to replace single quotes:

```
> gsub("[“”]", "\"", gsub("[‘’]", "'", text))
[1] "You don't get \"your\" money's worth"
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/VPDT3Q). Tested in both Linux and Windows, and works the same.

The `[“”]` construct is a positive [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches any single char defined in the class.

To normalize all chars similar to double quotes, you might want to use

```
> sngl_quot_rx = "[ʻʼʽ٬‘’‚‛՚︐]"
> dbl_quot_rx = "[«»““”„‟≪≫《》〝〞〟\＂″‶]"
> res = gsub(dbl_quot_rx, "\"", gsub(sngl_quot_rx, "'", `Encoding<-`(text, "UTF8"))) 
> cat(res, sep="\n")
You don't get "your" money's worth
```

Here, `[«»““”„‟≪≫《》〝〞〟＂″‶]` matches

```
«   00AB  LEFT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
»   00BB  RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
“   05F4  HEBREW PUNCTUATION GERSHAYIM
“   201C  LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
”   201D  RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
„   201E  DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
‟   201F  DOUBLE HIGH-REVERSED-9 QUOTATION MARK
≪  226A  MUCH LESS-THAN
≫  226B  MUCH GREATER-THAN
《  300A  LEFT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET
》  300B  RIGHT DOUBLE ANGLE BRACKET
〝  301D  REVERSED DOUBLE PRIME QUOTATION MARK
〞  301E  DOUBLE PRIME QUOTATION MARK
〟  301F  LOW DOUBLE PRIME QUOTATION MARK
＂  FF02  FULLWIDTH QUOTATION MARK
″   2033  DOUBLE PRIME
‶   2036  REVERSED DOUBLE PRIME
```

The `[ʻʼʽ٬‘’‚‛՚︐]` is used to normalize some chars similar to single quotes:

```
ʻ  02BB  MODIFIER LETTER TURNED COMMA
ʼ  02BC  MODIFIER LETTER APOSTROPHE
ʽ  02BD  MODIFIER LETTER REVERSED COMMA
٬  066C  ARABIC THOUSANDS SEPARATOR
‘  2018  LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
’  2019  RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
‚  201A  SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
‛  201B  SINGLE HIGH-REVERSED-9 QUOTATION MARK
՚   055A  ARMENIAN APOSTROPHE
︐  FE10  PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL COMMA
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, It works when only a string is passed but when a character vector is passed it sees to fail, not sure if anything to do with my R environment. Updated the question with it. Could you please check?

Comment: Yes, just a sec, I am adding more details.

Comment: Sorry that seemed to be my session issue. I restarted Rstudio, it works fine. I'll just upvote your answer (not marking as answer) as I'd want to know if any text mining package could do that on the go (without explicitly defining the symbols by us). Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ironically, this `['ʻʼʽ٬‘’‚‛]` break's Rstudio editor. So doesn't work.

Comment: @amrrs That is a regex string, not an R string literal, I will post a usage example.

Comment: I thought I could use it inside enclosed double quotes as in here `gsub("[“”]", "\"", gsub("[‘’]", "'", text))`. Woudn't work?

Comment: @amrrs There is a difference between how Windows and Linux distributions handle Unicode. So far, I made it work on Linux - see [this demo](https://ideone.com/WfN4wk). Well, from what I know, it may work differently, you may also try the `UCP` versions on your machine.

Comment: You must be right. Last couple of days, I've been seeing issues with Windows + RStudio + Foreign Characters!

Comment: @amrrs Got it finally, the encoding issue was the culprit. I updated the answer. Also, it seems R treats  `＂` as a regular ASCII `"`, so I escaped it. As for any libraries, I know no library that normalizes quotation marks.

Comment: Ok, today I learnt about [*proustr*](https://github.com/ColinFay/proustr#pr_normalize_punc), but it is not a generic quote normalization library. I believe the best solution here is a custom approach that I suggest. I added the double and single quotes from that package to my suggestions.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew when I use 

essay <- gsub("[“”]", "\"", gsub("[‘’]", "'", essay))

I'm getting this error when I try running my shiny app :

Warning: Error in source: functions.R:331:20: unexpected string constant.

But when I run it in a normal script it works. 
Would you know the fix please?

Answer (score 1):

There's a function in {proustr} to normalize punctuation, called `pr_normalize_punc()` :

https://github.com/ColinFay/proustr#pr_normalize_punc

It turns :

```
 => ″‶«  »“”`´„“ into "
 => ՚ ’ into ' 
 => … into ...
```

For example :

```
library(proustr)
a <- data.frame(text = "Il l՚a dit : « La ponctuation est chelou » !")
pr_normalize_punc(a, text)
# A tibble: 1 x 1
                                            text
*                                          <chr>
1 "Il l'a dit : \"La ponctuation est chelou\" !"
```

For your text :

```
pr_normalize_punc(data.frame( text = "You don‘t get “your” money’s worth"), text)
# A tibble: 1 x 1
                                    text
*                                  <chr>
1 "You don‘t get \"your\" money's worth"
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working:

`
> pr_normalize_punc(data.frame( text = new_text), text)
# A tibble: 5 x 1
                                          text
*                                        <chr>
1 "You don\u0092t get your money\u0092s worth"
2 "You don\u0092t get your money\u0092s worth"
3 "You don\u0092t get your money\u0092s worth"
4 "You don\u0092t get your money\u0092s worth"
5 "You don\u0092t get your money\u0092s worth"

`

Comment: Strange, this is working on my machine (check my answer update). What's your OS ?

Comment: I think it has to do with the System Locale, You might have been in a Locale other than English I suppose, Mine is English.

Comment: @amrrs The library is only for French, see the `pr_normalize_punc` function description: *Normalize a text written with usual french punctuation*. [The source code](https://github.com/ColinFay/proustr/blob/master/R/pr_norm_punct.R) reveals that the double quote pattern is `(″|‶|« | »|“|”|\`|´|„|“)` (please pay attention to spaces beside the chevrons!) and the single quote pattern deals with 3 chars only, `(՚|︐|’)`. [See demo](https://ideone.com/EFNe3J). I also think `\`` and `´`  look more like *single* quotes.

Comment: R's handling of native text on Windows is buggy. See, e.g., [this thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2017-September/074908.html). Use `text = utf8::as_utf8("You don‘t get “your” money’s worth")` to work around the bug.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `gsub` here for a base R option.  Replace each curly quoted term at a time.

```
text <- "You don‘t get “your” money’s worth"
new_text <- gsub("“(.*?)”", "\"\\1\"", text)
new_text <- gsub("’", "'", new_text)
new_text
[1] "You don‘t get \"your\" money's worth"
```

I have assumed here that your curly quotes are always balanced, i.e. they always wrap a word.  If not, then you might have to do more work.

Doing a blanket replacement of opening/closing double curly quotes may not play out as intended, if you want them to remain as is when *not* quoting a word.

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for answering, It still retains the single curly quote :-/.

Comment: I don't see any single curly quote in your question or sample data.  How can I code to something I cannot see?

Comment: Rats...I see it now...let me update.  I'm on a cell phone, small screen.

Comment: That's very impressive - to write from a phone!

Comment: @amrrs Obsessive is more accurate.  I have a Stack addiction :-P

Comment: My primary use-case here is to handle negations with apostrophe's but made the question more generic.