# R shiny app error: unexpected string constant in gsub function for curly quotes

Tags: r, text, shiny, gsub

I'm building shiny app that does a lot of text mining.

When I execute the function below in R to replace curly quotations “” and ‘’ by " and ' respectively, it works beautifully.

Example:

```
essay <- "peoples’ memories have “faded into mist” "
essay <- gsub("[“”]", "\"", gsub("[‘’]", "'", essay))
> essay
[1] "peoples' memories have \"faded into mist\" "
```

The above works great, but when I switch to shiny app file app.R, it doesn't work.

The gsub function is in a functions.R script which is called by source("functions.R") in my app.R script.

Now when I click Run App in my app.R file, the console prints out this error :

```
Warning: Error in source: functions.R:331:20: unexpected string constant
330:   # replace smart curly quotes by normal quotes
331:   essay <- gsub("[""]"
47: source
```

Does anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: please provide some reproducible example using dput()

Comment: i've edited. it should be clearer now

Comment: It must be an issue with encoding or normalization. Try something like ``essay <- gsub("[“”]", "\"", gsub("[‘’]", "'", `Encoding<-`(essay, "UTF8")))``

Comment: it didn't work :/ it has made curly quotes into â€œ, â€™, â€. and the app returned the same message error

Comment: Another approach to @WiktorStribiżew idea, I would try `options(encoding = "UTF-8")` at the start of the script

Comment: whether I run `essay <- gsub("[“”]", "\"", gsub("[‘’]", "'", Encoding<-(essay, "UTF8")))` OR `options(encoding = "UTF-8")` before running `essay <- gsub("[“”]", "\"", gsub("[‘’]", "'", essay))` I'm still getting this error: `ERROR: functions.R:342:20: unexpected string constant 341: 342: essay <- gsub("[""]" ^ –`

Comment: alternatively, is there a way I can normalize all possible quotes in a text?

Answer (score 0):

So R wasn't happy with [“”] and [‘’] in gsub in the shiny app.

Below is a great detailed answer from Wiktor Stribiżew for quotes normalization:
[Text Mining R Package & Regex to handle Replace Smart Curly Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173557/text-mining-r-package-regex-to-handle-replace-smart-curly-quotes)

But when the function is executed in the shiny app it spits the quotes as normal ones [""] and [''] therefore the function doesn't work.

I ended up using https://github.com/ColinFay/proustr#pr_normalize_punc

Cheers