# Regex to match quote with minimum number of words

Tags: java, regex, string, text, regex-group

I have the following text:

> Attorney General William Barr said the volume of information
>   compromised was “staggering” and the largest breach in U.S.
>   history.“This theft not only caused significant financial damage to
>   Equifax but invaded the privacy of many, millions of Americans and
>   imposed substantial costs and burdens on them as they had to take
>   measures to protect themselves from identity theft,” said Mr. Barr.

I want to match text within a quote however the quote must be a min of 5 words long otherwise it should be ignored.

Currently, I am using the following regex:

```
(?<=[\\“|\\"])[A-Za-z0-9\.\-][A-Za-z\s,:\\’]+(?=[\”|\"])
```

However, this would include the quote “staggering”  which is only 1 word so it should be ignored.

I realize I could accomplish this by repeating this part of Regex 5 times:

```
[A-Za-z\s,:\\’]+[A-Za-z\s,:\\’]+[A-Za-z\s,:\\’]+[A-Za-z\s,:\\’]+[A-Za-z\s,:\\’]+
```

However, I am wondering if there is a shorter and more concise way to achieve this? Perhaps by forcing the `\s` in `[]` to appear at least 5 times?

Thanks

Comment: Use https://regex101.com/r/fkSJnM/1, grab Group 1 values.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Brilliant!! Does the job.. (I'll will modify it myself so the quote is not included in actual match) Maybe add this as an answer with a bit of explanation and I will up-vote accept as answer? Thanks!

Comment: You should not use lookarounds, use a capturing group, the value is in `matcher.group(1)`. The `"` is identical as the leading and trailing marker, thus, you *must* use a capturing group.

Comment: isn't that also matching 2 words (inside quotes)?

Comment: @user85421 Last `+`  may be changed to `{1,4}`, or more, or just `{4,}`, all depends on the actual requirement.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Can you kindly explain why not to use lookarounds? Thanks

Comment: I have already, *The `"` is identical as the leading and trailing marker*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "unroll" the character class by taking out the whitespace matching pattern out of it, and use a `[<chars>]+(?:\s+[<chars>]+){4,}` like pattern. Note you should not use lookarounds here because `"` can be both a leading and a trailing marker, and that may result in unwanted matches. Use a capturing group instead  and access its value via `matcher.group(1)`.

You may use

```
String regex = "[“\"]([A-Za-z0-9.-][A-Za-z,:’]*(?:\\s+[A-Za-z0-9.-][A-Za-z,:’]*){4,})[”\"]";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fkSJnM/2).

Then, just grab the Group 1 value:

```
String line = "Attorney General William Barr said the volume of information compromised was “staggering” and the largest breach in U.S. history.“This theft not only caused significant financial damage to Equifax but invaded the privacy of many, millions of Americans and imposed substantial costs and burdens on them as they had to take measures to protect themselves from identity theft,” said Mr. Barr.";
String regex = "[“\"]([A-Za-z0-9.-][A-Za-z,:’]*(?:\\s+[A-Za-z0-9.-][A-Za-z,:’]*){4,})[”\"]";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(line);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()) {
    res.add(m.group(1));
}
System.out.println(res);
```

See the [online Java demo](https://ideone.com/mCnYg0).

**Pattern details**

- `[“"]` - `“` or `"`
- `([A-Za-z0-9.-][A-Za-z,:’]*(?:\\s+[A-Za-z0-9.-][A-Za-z,:’]*){4,})` - Group 1:

  - `[A-Za-z0-9.-][A-Za-z,:’]*` - an ASCII alphanumeric or `.` or `-` and then 0+ of ASCII letters, `,`, `:`, `’` chars
  - `(?:\s+[A-Za-z0-9.-][A-Za-z,:’]*){4,}` - four or more occurrences of

    - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
    - - `[A-Za-z0-9.-][A-Za-z,:’]*` - an ASCII alphanumeric or `.` or `-` and then 0+ of ASCII letters, `,`, `:`, `’` chars
- `[”"]` - `"` or `”`

Comment: Is there a POSIX expression for "any quote" or similar? `\p{Pi}` (Initial quote punctuation) and `\p{Pf}` (Final quote punctuation) looked promising, but match only `«` and `»` respectively. It seems a resonable class, given all the [variants of quotation marks](https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/quotation-marks).

Comment: @Bohemian There is no POSIX/Unicode Category class for quotation marks. One has to use a character class for that. Those are [chars from various punctuation and symbol subcategories](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%C2%AB%E2%80%B9%C2%BB%E2%80%BA%E2%80%9E%E2%80%9C%E2%80%9F%E2%80%9D%E2%80%99%22%E2%9D%9D%E2%9D%9E%E2%9D%AE%E2%9D%AF%E2%B9%82%E3%80%9D%E3%80%9E%E3%80%9F%EF%BC%82%E2%80%9A%E2%80%98%E2%80%9B%E2%9D%9B%E2%9D%9C%E2%9D%9F#title). I have also tried to sum that up in [an R answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173557) with a similar set of chars.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct regex that matches your case.

The one in the code snippet bellow *matches text within quotes 5 words long*,

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("“((\\b\\w+\\b)+.?( *)){5,}”", Pattern.DOTALL);

    String input = "Attorney General William Barr said the volume of "+
    "information compromised was “staggering” and the largest breach in"+
     "U.S. history.“This theft not only caused significant financial "+
     "damage to Equifax but invaded the privacy of many, millions of"+
     "Americans and imposed substantial costs and burdens on them as "+
     "they had to take measures to protect themselves from identity theft,” said Mr. Barr.";

    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);

    while (m.find()) {
      String s = m.group();
      System.out.print(s);  
    }
```

**Note**: You need to set a utf8 flag to compile those specific quote characters, '**“**' and '**”**'. 
So instead of `javac TheClass.java` use `javac -encoding utf8 TheClass.java`!